# Matplotlib takes very long to create images

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I'd like to create >1000 images in 2k resolution in a reasonable amount of time. But from what I've read matplotlib doesn't seem to be the fastest way to create images on python and currently it takes me 2-3 hours just to create 1000 images. Does anyone know if there's ways to optimize matplotlib?

Here's the code:

```
data = file.read()
iter = np.linspace(0,5000,5000).astype(int)
hillshade = es.hillshade(data, azimuth=180, altitude=1)
x_colormap = ListedColormap(newcolors)
t = 0
for j in iter:
    data[data < j] = data.max()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(6, 5)
    plt.imshow(data, cmap=x_colormap, norm=colors.LogNorm(1, data.max() - 1))
    ax.imshow(hillshade, cmap="Greens", alpha=0.2)
    ax.axis('off')
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig(r'path', dpi=1200, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.0)
    t = t + 1
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Do you need to view the images in between? You could just create matrix representations of the images and save those instead. You can also look into synthesizers. You can view and save them later outside the loop.

Comment: I'd rather not show the images in between but I rely on the values set for the parameters in those imshow functions. Can you tell me how to create matrix representations with the same parameter values like  "cmap="Greens"" etc?